# Invoke a button action from ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

while invoking an action button say from viewDidLoad by default what is the value of id ? For instance

```
- (IBAction)findInvoice:(id)sender {
....
....
}
```

I am currently using [self findInvoice:nil]; in viewDidLoad and I pass Invoice reference to a editable text field. It works. Is that correct

Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking us if it worked? You ran the code. Did it work or not?

Comment: @rmaddy It does work. I am asking because I don't want have an unknown problem if any down the line

Comment: Dealing with unknown problems is what testing is for. In general, what you are doing is fine. It's your code that determines if it is fine or not.

Comment: @user1509593 You should read the documentation instead of asking. The value of `sender` is the sender of the action, i. e. the instance of `UIControl` that invokes the method; it is the button itself in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's ok to do that, but in such cases I prefer moving the logic to a separate method and call it from everywhere.

```
- (void)findInvoice {
    ...
}

- (IBAction)findInvoiceButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self findInvoice];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self findInvoice];
}
```

Comment: +1, that's what I'm talking about, this is **the** correct approach.

Comment: what to do,if he need the sender for other purposes ?

Comment: I like this answer better. I dont do anything with id

Answer (score 2):

No issues with your call. Make sure that you are not using the `sender` inside the `findInvoice` method for any other purposes.

When a button is clicked,`(id)sender` should be the clicked button.It representing `id` as the datatype. So you can pass manually nil or whatever you need.

you can call this method as two ways,

```
[self findInvoice:nil]; //sender should be nil;

[self findInvoice:self.settingsButton];//sender should be settingsButton;
```

Also you can trigger it when a button is clicked.

```
- (IBAction)findInvoice:(id)sender {

  UIButton *btnClicked = (UIButton *)sender; //it should be nil when called as [self findInvoice:nil];

}
```